# customize errors "required" Symfony 1.4 (dynamic label)

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

In "ProjectConfiguration" I can customize the output errors, such

```
sfValidatorBase::setDefaultMessage('min_length', 'Min% min_length% sign');
sfValidatorBase::setDefaultMessage('required', 'Label required');
```

But for the field "required", I can not substitute the dynamic field name, like this:

```
sfValidatorBase::setDefaultMessage('required', 'Label %label% required');
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Or you will have to hack into the global `sfValidatorBase`.

---

If you take the example of `min_length` error, it is throwing like this (in [`sfValidatorString`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/1.4/lib/validator/sfValidatorString.class.php#L64-67)):

```
throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'min_length', array('value' => $value, 'min_length' => $this->getOption('min_length')));
```

As you can see, it takes parameters for `value` and `min_length` since the message is defined like this :

```
$this->addMessage('min_length', '"%value%" is too short (%min_length% characters min).');
```

So it will automatically replace each *variable* with `%....%`.

For `required` error, it's throwing from the [`sfValidatorBase`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/1.4/lib/validator/sfValidatorBase.class.php#L306-327) (the one which is extended by all validator):

```
throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'required');
```

As you can see, nothing is given as third parameter, so you can't configure extra parameter. If you want to do so, you should change:

```
throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'required', array('label' => $this->getOption('label')));
```

But this change will be inside the Symfony repository. And this `sfValidatorBase` is extended on every validator, I don't know how you can apply this modification. At least, you know where do make changes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Just need to override all the validators. But hacking core is not correct, I think.

Comment: @Karmazzin I think too. Of course, you can override the `clean` method in all your validator to add the third parameter.